# Error when trying to install Ruby 3.0.0 through RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line-interface, homebrew, rvm

I get this endless loop when trying to upgrade Ruby through RVM:

```
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.12-next', you are using older version '1.29.3'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/11.2/x86_64/ruby-3.0.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
```

Is there any other methods I can use to do such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it using homebrew by running 'brew upgrade ruby'. That should upgrade it to the latest Ruby version.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!